No net torque about principal axis

I’m trying to follow the proof for why no net torque is required to sustain constant rotation about a principal axis.
I am confused by the proof by contradiction above. How does “rotating the axis and starting the process at a later time” establish that the line of $\mathbf{L}$ always passes through a dot it once initially passed through?
Source: Morin’s Intro to Classical Mechanics

I think the logic here is as follows:
For the general case, the direction of angular momentum $\boldsymbol{L}$ is not parallel to the direction of rotation $\boldsymbol{\omega}$, due to the nature of the mass moment of inertia tensor.
$$ \boldsymbol{L} = {\rm I}\, \boldsymbol{\omega} \tag{1} $$
But when no torque is applied, the angular momentum axis remains fixed, and the axis of rotation changes with time. We call that precession. In order to fix the axis of rotation, a torque needs to be applied to keep $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ on a fixed axis. This torque is given by the equation
$$ \boldsymbol{\tau} = \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{L} \tag{2}$$
But in the specific scenario where $\boldsymbol{\tau}=0$, this means that angular momentum and rotation axis are parallel to each other such that $\boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{L} = 0$
The general equation for torque comes from
$$ \boldsymbol{\tau} = \tfrac{{\rm d} \boldsymbol{L}}{{\rm d}t}  = {\rm I} \boldsymbol{\alpha} + \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{L} \tag{3}$$
where $\boldsymbol{\alpha} = \tfrac{ {\rm d}\boldsymbol{\omega}}{{\rm d}t} $.
